# angularjs ui-calendar how to change title in header?

Tags: angularjs

I want to make title like it should display week1 week2..not the default title?

Now it is showing (Jan 26 — Feb 1 2014)

```
 header: {
    left: 'prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek'
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do these changes in fullcalender.js
Set title format like this

```
titleFormat: {
    week: "W",
    }

function updateTitle() {
        //alert(currentView.title);
        var weekNo= currentView.title%4;
        if(weekNo==0){
                weekNo=4
            }
        header.updateTitle("Week "+weekNo);
    }
```

and set update title like above.